# Re.compile search doesn't show the full string

Tags: python, regex-greedy

In a text I'd like to find if the text contains the following string:

`"http://p.thisistheurl.com/v/"` after that anything until `"jpg"`.

So this is the python code that I wrote:

```
asdf = 'http://p.thisistheurl.com/v/adzl25/4321567/543276123/865.jpg'

regex = re.compile(r'http://p.thisistheurl.com/v/(.)*jpg')

regex.search(asdf)

<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 60), match='http://p.thisistheurl.com/v/adzl25/4321567/543276'>
```

As you can see the result doesn't show the whole string with the `"jpg"`. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Try an online regex debugger eg regex101. It will explain your regex and show what is matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any guarantee that the characters displayed after `match=` are actually the complete contents of the string that got matched. It probably just cuts off after 50 characters or so.

Looking at [cpython's implementation of `SRE_Match.__repr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_sre.c#L2315), this is indeed the case: the `50R` right there is the smoking gun.

```
result = PyUnicode_FromFormat(
        "<%s object; span=(%d, %d), match=%.50R>",
        Py_TYPE(self)->tp_name,
self->mark[0], self->mark[1], group0);
```

If you access the actual matched string, rather than inspect it from the match object's printed representation, it goes all the way to `jpg`:

```
>>> import re
>>> asdf = 'http://p.thisistheurl.com/v/adzl25/4321567/543276123/865.jpg'
>>> regex = re.compile(r'http://p.thisistheurl.com/v/(.)*jpg')
>>> print(regex.search(asdf).group(0))
http://p.thisistheurl.com/v/adzl25/4321567/543276123/865.jpg
```

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you for the answer sir!